# Multithread node.js instagram parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Working on node.js instagram parser. At the moment I have 1 thread with proxy working code, but I'm not sure how to make multithread architecture:

```
'use strict';
var InstagramPrivateAPI = {};

InstagramPrivateAPI = {};
InstagramPrivateAPI.V1 = require(__dirname + '/client/v1');
InstagramPrivateAPI.Helpers = require(__dirname + '/helpers');
var acc = require(__dirname + "/client/v1/account");
var med = require(__dirname + "/client/v1/media")

var Promise = require('../bluebird');
var _ = require('../lodash/');

module.exports = InstagramPrivateAPI;

var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var device = new Client.Device('maksgmn');
var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage(__dirname + '/cookies/maksgmn.json');
var session = new Client.Session(device, storage);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var fs = require('fs');
var proxyArray = fs.readFileSync('proxy.txt').toString().split("\n");
var usernamesArray = fs.readFileSync('usernames.txt').toString().split("\n");

var proxy = "http://" + proxyArray[getRandomInt(0,proxyArray.length)]
var username = usernamesArray[getRandomInt(0,usernamesArray.length)]

console.log(proxy)
console.log(username)

Client.Request.setProxy(proxy);


acc.searchForUser(session, username) //поиск id пользователя
    .then(function(profile) {
        return profile.id
    })
    .then(function(someId) {  //получение промиса lenta
        var feed = new Client.Feed.UserMedia(session, someId);
        var lenta = Promise.mapSeries(_.range(0, 1), function() {
            return feed.get();
        }).then(function(lenta) {
            return {id: someId, fd : lenta}
        })
        return lenta
    })
    .then(function(results) {  //обработка промиса и получение ленты пользователя
        // result should be Media[][]
        var media1 = _.flatten(results.fd);
        var urls1 = _.map(media1, function(medium) {
                //var arr1 = medium.params.images[0].url;
            var arr1 = []

            try {
                arr1 = medium.params.images[0].url
            } catch (err) {
                //console.log("lala")
            }

            return arr1;
            //console.log(medium.params.carouselMedia.images[0].url)
        })

        //console.log(urls1)

        return {id : results.id, linksNoCarousel : urls1, med : media1}
    })
    .then(function(res){

        var urls2 = _.map(res.med, function(medium) {

            var arr2 = []

            try {
                arr2 = medium.params.images[0][0].url
                //console.log(arr2)
            } catch (err) {

            }
            return arr2        
        })

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (typeof res.linksNoCarousel[i] == "undefined")
                res.linksNoCarousel[i] = urls2[i];
        }

        var arr3 = []

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            arr3[i] = res.linksNoCarousel[i]
        }

        return {id : res.id, links : arr3}

    })
    .then(function(mediaAndId) {
        acc = acc.getById(session, mediaAndId.id)
            .then(function(account) {
                //console.log(account.params)
                let avatar = account.params.profilePicUrl;
                let fullName = account.params.fullName;
                let bio = account.params.biography;
                let media0 = mediaAndId.links[0];
                let media1 = mediaAndId.links[1];
                let media2 = mediaAndId.links[2];
                let media3 = mediaAndId.links[3];
                let media4 = mediaAndId.links[4];

                console.log(avatar);
                console.log(fullName);
                console.log(bio);
                console.log(media0);
                console.log(media1);
                console.log(media2);
                console.log(media3);
                console.log(media4);
            })
    })
```

I would like it to work like multithread to be much more faster with proxies. As far as I'm working with node.js 2nd day, asking that question: how to do that?

Comment: What exactly is too slow? Node.js typically isn't multithreaded. You're already doing most things asynchrously.

Comment: I haven't measured it before but you know... I need smth like threads or instances for it to take new proxy everytime and work maybe with new session or stuff like that

Comment: If it's just a single machine and you want to take advantage of more than one core, node.js has a cluster mechanism:  https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Comment: @user239247 What exactly do you mean by "every time"? Do you want to make requests to all proxies, not a single random one?

Comment: maybe to single random actually but I'm not sure how it works at the moment with loops